# read autoincrement Id without running db.run and without for comprehension in Slick in single transaction

Tags: scala, slick

I need to insert into a table and, based on the return Id, insert into other tables. Unable to run for-comprehension on both Scala collection and DBCollection.

```
 def savebook(book: Book, bookReaders: Seq[BookReaders]) = {
  val transformedBookReaders = Seq[BookReaders]()
  val action1 = bookDAO.insertRow(book).map { id =>
    transformedBookReaders :+ bookReaders.map { bookReader=> new BookAssociation(None, id, bookReader.moduleId, bookReader.userId, bookReader.roleId) }
  }
  val action2 = bookAssocDao.insertRows(transformedBookReaders )
  db.run(action1.andThen(action2).transactionally)
}
```

My second action is not inserting any row.

Answer (score 0):

If `action1` has not run at the time that `action2` is constructed, then `transformedBookReaders` will be empty and nothing will happen. If you could change `action` to produce a collection of `BookReader` instead of depending on side effects, then `action2` could be constructed

```
def savebook(book: Book, bookReaders: Seq[BookReaders]) = {
  val action1 = bookDAO.insertRow(book).map { id =>
    bookReaders.map { bookReader=> new BookAssociation(None, id, bookReader.moduleId, bookReader.userId, bookReader.roleId)
  }
  val action2 = readers => bookAssocDao.insertRows( readers )
  db.run(action1.andThen(action2).transactionally)
}
```

I may have misunderstood what `insertRow()` and `insertRows()` do.

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was to run non database transaction code in for comprehension.  I need to iterate over scala collection while I was performing DB transaction code in for comprehension.

I found one link(http://virtuslab.slides.com/pdolega/slick-101#/94) which explains very nicely how to run non database transaction code in for comprehensions by using DBIO.successful

```
 def saveBook(book: Book, bookModules: Seq[BookModule]) = {
    def createBookModuleMapping(bookId: Int) = {
      bookModules.map { bookModule =>
        new bookModule(None, bookId, bookModule.moduleId, bookModule.isActive)
      }
    }

    val action1 = for {
      bookId<-bookDao.insert(book)
      bookModule <- DBIO.successful(createBookModuleMapping(bookId))
      ids <- bookModuleDao.insertRows(bookModule)
    } yield ()

    db.run(action1.transactionally)

  }
```